# Removing results from a list where they exist in another list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

In my application, you are able to link users to the organization where they are stored in a list, 'userList':

```
List<OrganizationUserViewModel> userList = new List<OrganizationUserViewModel>();

foreach (var ou in org.Users.OrderBy(x => x.User.UserName).ToList())
{
    var user = Gateway.Instance.Map<User, OrganizationUserViewModel>(ou.User);
    user.Organization_UserId = ou.Organization_UserId;
    userList.Add(user);
}
```

These users can be selected in a menu which displays all users that are connected to other organizations that are able to be linked.

This snippet of code populates the lists of organisations with all of the users attached to them:

```
foreach (var childOrg in viewModel.ChildOrganizations)
{
    childOrg.Users = new List<OrganizationUserViewModel>();
    var users = this._organizationManager.GetOrganizationUsers(childOrg.OrganizationId);
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        var u = Gateway.Instance.Map<User, OrganizationUserViewModel>(user.User);
        u.Organization_UserId = user.Organization_UserId;
        childOrg.Users.Add(u);
    }
}
```

My issue is that I am required to display this selectable list without any of the already selected users in 'userList'. For instance, if a user called "Apple" has been linked, they should not appear in the selectable list.

What would be the most efficient way to approach this? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "most efficient" mean? It's nebulous and ill-defined.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I mean performance wise, without having to go the route of multiple foreach statements and the like. I am still a relative novice, so please forgive any nasty bits of code!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming both lists have same datatype, Linq to the rescue:

```
var allowedSelectionsList = selectableList.Except(selectedList).ToList();
```

?

Comment: And a proper .Equals-implementation. :)

Comment: @faester ...well that would also require a proper `GetHashCode` implementation, but I was under the assumption that object equality would suffice (i.e. the same set of objects are being referenced by both lists)

Comment: Would GetHashCode be used for list member comparison? You might be right about reference equality, but I couldn't tell from the OPs code. (I will gladly remove comment, the comment was solely meant as a reminder.)

Comment: Thank you very much, let me have a go an implementing this and I will get back to you!

Comment: @faester : The two go hand in hand, if you provide an equality implementation, you must also provide GetHashCode too, even if this problem does not require it, otherwise you're saving up problems for some later time.

Comment: Hi Spender,

I have tried implementing this, and it looks really close, the issue is now that the allowedUserList is returning all of the values because the foreign key seems to differ between the two selections:

http://gyazo.com/8eadbd8dc24f4bc41196bc4a4770366a

Would it be possible to use a similar solution comparing the 'UserId' of the two entries?

Thanks for your ongoing help!

Comment: @spender: that is of course true, but I was curious about list. This is not.that relevant here of course.